# PHP Startup error: Unable to load dynamic library 'solr.so'

Tags: php, solr, centos7

After upgrading my php on Centos 7 Linux machine, I began getting this error:

[root@ip-172-31-13-94 workarea]# php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'solr.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2020 10:03:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Upgrade the `solr` library to your current PHP version (`pecl install solr`) and make sure that the version you're using is the correct one for the installed version.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I ensure that I have the correct version of solr for my php (if that's what you meant)?

Comment: You re-install it. You might have upgraded your PHP installation through your package system without updating the solr module (which might have been installed manually earlier). . You can reinstall the solr module by running `pecl install solr` again, which should recompile and install it .Another option is to check if it's available through the package repository from where you installed PHP (probably through `yum` on CentOS?)